# Memory Error in Python Machine Learning Script

Tags: python

I'm getting a memory error in Python. Using an machine with 4GB ram, just recently installed Ubuntu plenty of HD space. Running the following machine learning script: https://github.com/mrmotallebi/synthesizing_obama_network_training

I have confirmed that I'm using the 64-bit version of Python. I'm new to machine learning, should I just setup a VM with significantly more RAM?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "run.py", line 225, in <module>    
main()   File "run.py", line 222, in main   s = Speech()   File "run.py", 
line 42, in __init__    self.loadData()   File 
"/home/gabriel/Downloads/synthesizing_obama_network_training- 
master/util.py", line 129, in loadData  meani, stdi, meano, stdo = 
 self.normalize(inps, outps)   File 
 "/home/gabriel/Downloads/synthesizing_obama_network_training- 
 master/util.py", line 103, in normalize    meani, stdi = 
normalizeData(inps["training"], "save/" + self.args.save_dir, 
 "statinput", ["fea%02d" % x for x in range(inps["training"] 
[0].shape[1])], normalize=self.args.normalizeinput)   File 
"/home/gabriel/Downloads/synthesizing_obama_network_training- 
master/util.py", line 48, in normalizeData  std = np.std(allstrokes, 0)   
File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3242, in std  **kwargs)   File 
"/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 140, in _std      
keepdims=keepdims)   File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 117, in _var     x = 
asanyarray(arr - arrmean) 
MemoryError
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If the data set that you are using occupies more than 4GB then the RAM memory cannot allocate all of it. You should then use a technique called batch processing that collects data from the hard drive in batches and stores it temporarily in the RAM memory.

Hope that is useful!